# How to write a SWT based GUI in Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I learned how to write a SWT based application following this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SWT/article.html). However, I don't know how to move forward to a GUI eclipse plug-in.

The plug-in I am writing is right-clicking on any IJavaElement node in Package Explorer, it will show one more action, that action will bring up a GUI dialog letting me fill out some value and save the result to my database.

Right now my problems are:

- I can write a stand alone SWT based GUI application, but I don't know how to put the following code snippet in `public void run(IAction action)`

  ```
  Display display = new Display();
  Shell shell = new Shell(display);

  shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
  shell.open();

  while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
          display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
  ```

  All SWT tutorial I found was create Shell, Display in a main, but looks like you should do differently in Eclipse plug-in. Do I must use JFace to create Dialog while developing Eclipse plug-in?
- Without adding `org.eclipse.swt(.cocoa.macosx.x86_64.source)` in plugin.xml dependency, I could show that action only if I right-clicked on `IJavaElement`. But when I try to run that action, eclipse will show

  ```
  Problem Occurred
  Unhandled event loop exception
  Not implemented [multiple displays]
  ```

  I guess it's because I new one more `Display`. However, if I added `org.eclipse.swt(.cocoa.macosx.x86_64.source)` into plugin.xml dependency, my action won't even show up in popup menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is creating a new Display - you should not do it when creating an Eclipse plugin. Eclipse already has display and event loop running.

Try putting just this code in your action:

```
Shell shell = new Shell(Display.getCurrent());

shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
shell.open();
```